# How to combine the weights of 5 trained models to predict test dataset with better accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

Am using MNIST Fashion data set
1 - i have divided train data into 5 different location, which each contain only 2 class images.
2 - i have trained each location data set in different model and test data content all (0 to 9) class images for prediction.

Question->how to combine all 5 trained models to one model which can predict my test data with better accuracy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can combine the output from this 5 separate models. I am listing some of them.

1. Simply add the probability obtained for each class in those 5 models and then whichever is having maximum, give the verdict as that class.
2. Go with voting pattern. Which class is being predicted as output by most number of classifiers. In case of tie, check whose probability is highest.
3. Ensemble them. Pass the final hidden layer (or layers) features of all classifiers to another network. This new network can be as simple as a single dense layer or some complicated [boosted tree models](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier).